# Show Activity Indicator when opening a new controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

hello whenever I try to navigate from one controller to another and pass data along with it, the next controller doesn't comes up instantly, instead it takes some time like 1 to 3 sec. I want to show spinner when user clicks the cell or collection view cell and hide the spinner after next controller comes up. I don't know how can I do this. I mean I have tried to use the spinner on viewDidLoad of next controller but still the problem is I want to display when user clicks it and hide when next controller comes up.. 
I am launching another controller like this

```
  let tripDetailController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tripDetailController") as! TripDetailController
        tripDetailController.trip = trip
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tripDetailController, animated: true)
```

Comment: i think this delay might be only on simulator , or you are making some operations on the main thread

Comment: well I don't know. On the next controller I am displaying the data in the viewdidLoad function that has been passed by the previous controller

Comment: I have the same issue at the moment (only with iOS simulator and not every run)

Answer (score 0):

When you detect that a cell is selected, create and start animating a UIActivityIndicatorView in the middle of the screen (or wherever you want it). Right before you present the new View Controller, stop animating and remove the spinner.

Comment: I am not using segue

Comment: Same idea. Remove the spinner right before you switch view controllers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using delegation? I would make the first controller a delegate of the second, and in the viewDidLoad() or viewDidAppear() of the second controller, you notify the first controller that the view has indeed appeared or loaded, and then you hide the spinner from your delegate method in the first controller.